# Array.prototype.fill intended behavior on reference types

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know that this is the future technology, but MDN doesn't cover all use-cases, ans almost any environment already supports this method. Here's an example I am worried about:

```
var groups = new Array(4);
groups.fill([]);
groups[0].push(1);

groups[0] // --> [ 1 ]
groups[1] // --> [ 1 ]
```

So it's not just fills `groups` with empty array, it fills `groups` with the same one empty array! 
Is this an intended behavior or things can change in the future?

Comment: `[]` is just a value like every other. `fill` won't bother cloning it, why would it?

Comment: [`Array(4).fill(Array).map((A) => new A);`](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ih3rl7bg/) - the thing is, initialising an array of objects from an array of constructors is no less readable in ECMA-6. :-)

Comment: @Emissary: How about `Array(4).fill(0).map(Array)`?

Comment: @Bergi been there, tried that... `map` passes 3 unwanted parameters. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the intended behavior according to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.fill). The value is not cloned.